# Few understanding problems

Tags: grammar

I started reading "Tess of the d'urbervilles" which i cant understand some parts ....

1. Durbeyfield walked on a few steps in a dream then sat down
2. Now dont you get angry! ==》 here the sentence is exclamatory
3. Six helpless creatures who had not ask to be born at all,much less to be part of the irresponsible Durbeyfield family

The second part of the third one "much less ..." i know theres a connection between this and the first part but i cant figure it out .. so whats the meaning of the whole sentence

And again in the third one what will be the diffrrence if we add a after be "much less *to be a part* of the ...."

Comment: This might attract better answers on [literature.se].

Comment: Actual text:  If the heads of the Durbeyfield household chose to sail into difficulty, disaster, starvation, disease, degradation, death, thither were these half-dozen little captives under hatches compelled to sail with them—six helpless creatures, who had never been asked if they wished for life on any terms, much less if they wished for it on such hard conditions as were involved in being of the shiftless house of Durbeyfield.

Comment: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/110/110-h/110-h.htm

Answer (score 1):

(1)"...Walked a few steps then sat down" is simple enough, isn't it? "In a dream" describes his state of mind.

(2) is the imperative (telling someone not to be angry).

(3) The children had not asked to be born. They had *certainly* not asked to be born into that particular family.